# Django Rest Framework shows error when try to save User in new Django 1.7

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I could save users normally with version 1.6, but i decide to make a new project with this new version of Django, and all code is the same, but when i try to create a new user with the frontend (created with Restangular) shows me an error. The same error is shown in the form of the DRF's API. It asks me details like date_joined and last_login :O No problem, i write them. But DRF shows:
" needs to have a value for field "user" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

In the terminal works perfect just with

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
u = User()
u.username="newuser"
u.save()
```

I have multiple models that works like m2m relations, like:

```
class Inscription(models.Model):
    categoria = models.ForeignKey('app.Category')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='inscriptions')
    signed_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='inscription_signed_by')
    created_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    udpated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) 
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.categoria.nombre, self.user.first_name)
```

But this was working fine in the last versión, i don't know what i did wrong :(
I use DRF 2.4.3 and Python 3.3.5. ¿How can i make DRF works correctly ?
Thank you very much!

Edit:
I use it like this with router.register(r'users', UserViewSet):

```
class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    model = User
    write_only_fields = ('password',) 
    lookup_field = 'id'
```

Comment: In addition to ModelViewSet, I was working with the model User in nested serializers, and they was working fine in another url. But now that doesn't work.

Comment: No, i didn't update python. My current is 3.3.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running into a [known bug](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1642) with Python 3 and Django REST Framework 2.4. The issue is that the behavior of many-to-many relationships and `getattr` is different in Python 3, and there was a change in 2.3.14 that broke it for serializers.

You have two options for fixing this, none of which are really that great:

- Downgrade Django REST Framework to 2.3.13. This will bring it back before the change that broke it, and it's easily `pip` installable.
- Upgrade to Django REST Framework 3.0. [It's not released yet](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/version-3.0/docs/topics/3.0-announcement.md), but it's worth a shot if you can't downgrade.

Comment: Thank you! DRF is new, i'm going to study it to use it. Later i'll tell you :)

Comment: With DRF 3, i had many problems, what a pity, it showed me several errors. I downgrade to 2.3.13, and it's working again. Thank you!!!